# "That strikes one for me"...what's it mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases, expressions, phrase-meaning

What's the "one" mean here? Is this taken from baseball? Can the idiom be grammatically used in other persons besides the first?

Comment: Or is it 'That's strike one for me?'

Comment: A Google Books search doesn't yield any matches for "that strikes one for me," which strongly suggests that (1) the idiom is misreported here, or (2) it isn't an idiom at all, or (3) it is such a recently adopted idiom that Google Books has yet to register it. I think that options (1) and (2) are far more likely explanations than option (3).

Comment: Please provide a reference where you saw this. I agree with @AndySemyonov that it's more likely to be _that's strike one_. That's a metaphor referring to the 3 strikes in baseball.

Comment: I see. What does it mean to say, "That's strike one for me!" or "That's strike two [or three] for me!"?

Comment: Hickory Dickory Dock/ two mice ran up the clock/ the clock struck one/ **but the other one got away!**

Comment: You get 3 strikes and you're out.  That's the first one.

Answer (score 2):

In answer to the poster's question in a comment beneath his original question, "That's strike one for me" means "I've already missed one chance to succeed at whatever task I'm talking about."

The notion is that in baseball a batter who accumulates three strikes in a particular time at bat is out and has no further opportunity to hit the ball or otherwise get on base until his team completes another cycle through the batting order. So metaphorically having "one strike for me" or "two strikes for me" means getting closer to being "called out."

When used metaphorically (in a non-baseball context), referring to a particular number of strikes is usually intended only as a loose approximation of the person's nearness to being figuratively "retired" (fired, demoted, or subjected to some other negative consequence). In U.S. penal law, however, a "three strikes law" refers to a statute prescribing imprisonment for life without possibility of parole for persons convicted of felonies on three separate occasions. According to the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-strikes_law) on the subject, "Twenty-four [U.S.] states have some form of 'three-strikes' law."

Comment: Where you say “retired” that is also a baseball term — after strike 3 the batter is out and he is said to have been retired. It has nothing to do with retiring from a job or being fired or demoted from a job. And 3 strikes laws are not U.S. laws, they are only in some individual states.